# How to sort QList<QVariant> in Qt?

Tags: qt, sorting, qvariant

I have the following datastructure.

```
QList<QVariant> fieldsList
```

How can I sort this list? This list contains strings. I want to sort the `fieldList` alphabetically?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would do sorting in the following way:

```
 // Compare two variants.
 bool variantLessThan(const QVariant &v1, const QVariant &v2)
 {
     return v1.toString() < v2.toString();
 }

 int doComparison()
 {
     [..]
     QList<QVariant> fieldsList;

     // Add items to fieldsList.

     qSort(fieldsList.begin(), fieldsList.end(), variantLessThan);
 }
```

Update:
in QT5 the `qSort` obsoleted. But it is still available to support old source codes. It is highly recommended to use `std::sort` instead of that in new codes.

Answer (score 75):

In Qt5, it seems `qSort` is deprecated. It's recommended to use:

```
#include <algorithm>
QList<QVariant> fieldsList;
std::sort(fieldsList.begin(), fieldsList.end());
```

Reference: [site](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html#qSort)

Comment: Just a short note that apparently it is still valid in Qt4: [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qSort)

Answer (score -3):

```
int n;
int i;
for (n=0; n < fieldsList.count(); n++)
{
    for (i=n+1; i < fieldsList.count(); i++)
    {
        QString valorN=fieldsList.at(n).field();
        QString valorI=fieldsList.at(i).field();
        if (valorN.toUpper() > valorI.toUpper())
        {
            fieldsList.move(i, n);
            n=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always avoid doing manual sorting unless you have a good reason for that. This is inefficient and makes the code unnecessarily more confusing.